# Is there a performance difference between INNER JOIN USING and INNER JOIN ON?

Tags: postgresql

Assuming two tables:

```
students (student_id INT, class_id INT);
instructors (instructor_id INT, class_id INT);
```

is there a performance difference between these two:

```
SELECT * FROM
students INNER JOIN instructors USING (class_id);

SELECT * FROM
student INNER JOIN instructors ON students.class_id = instructors.class_id;
```

Comment: There is no performance difference but I prefer the second one for clarity.

Comment: Why don't you test it.

Comment: There is a slight performance difference: the first query returns 3 columns, the second - 4. More data to return - slower query. But is you specify the column list - the queries will be equal.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that generally there would be no performance penalty while I prefer the first one for being more sharp. Or even:

```
SELECT * FROM
students NATURAL INNER JOIN instructors;
```

As always `explain` and a common sense is your perfect guide. There can be situations where `NATURAL` is not exactly what you want because it automagically select all fields with the same names. There are situations where `USING` doesn't cover your joining rules. I personally try to write as less code as possible making it as readable as I can. And everything like `NATURAL` or `USING` is just a syntax sugar that makes my code more readable.

Comment: Just as a caveat:  natural joins have implicit criteria.  This can run you into trouble as your schema evolves and you accidently add the same column name to both tables down the road (something like valid_from or the like).  I prefer for this reason to keep join conditions explicit.